# pandas | get data from another dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

`products`

```
+------------+--------------------+
| item_name  | item_tags          |
+------------+--------------------+
| blue_shirt | summer,winter,blue |
|            |                    |
+------------+--------------------+
| red_skirt  | spring,summer      |
+------------+--------------------+
```

and `orders`

```
+------------+
| item       |
+------------+
| blue_shirt |
+------------+
| red_skirt  |
+------------+
```

and I want to create a new column in `orders`: when `products.item_name` == `orders.item`, I want to take the value of `products.item_tags` and add it to orders.

I've tried:

```
orders['ItemTags'] = products.query("{0}=={1}".format(orders['item'], products['item_name']))['Tags']
```

But it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way we can do this is with creating a dictionary from your products table, with your item_name column as your `key` and your item_tags column as your `value`, and then `map` it onto your orders item column:

```
products_dict = dict(zip(products.item_name,products.item_tags))
orders['item_tags'] = orders['item'].map(products_dict)
```

Output

```
orders
Out[83]: 
         item           item_tags
0  blue_shirt  summer,winter,blue
1   red_skirt       spring,summer
```

Comment: brilliant, exactly what I needed. I tried all sorts of things with `map` but didn't think about creating a dict first. thanks!

Comment: Welcome, glad it works. Another way to get there would be with merging the 2 datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using of the `merge` function.

```
pd.merge(df_orders, df_products, left_on='item', right_on='item_name').drop(['item_name'], axis = 1)
```

By using `merge` method you can pass the both `products` and `orders` datasets and specify the column(s) for the `join` operations.

```
import pandas as pd
df_products = pd.DataFrame(data={'item_name': ['blue_shirt', 'red_skirt'], 'item_tags': ['summer,winter,blue','spring,summer']})
df_orders = pd.DataFrame(data={'item': ['blue_shirt','red_skirt']})
df_orders = pd.merge(df_orders, df_products, left_on='item', right_on='item_name').drop(['item_name'], axis = 1)
print(df_orders)
```

Output

```
   item           item_tags
0  blue_shirt  summer,winter,blue
1  red_skirt       spring,summer
```